# Jquery slider above all divs on fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, absolute

I am coding up a page and i have a jquery slider on it called all in one slider. I have chosen to put a fixed nav at the top which is always visable during scrolling. problem is when i scroll past the slider the slider is above the nav.

I have tried positioning etc but it is not working and z-index:1000;

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code? Perhaps on - http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

try setting the z-index of the slider negative:

```
#slider {
z-index:-99;
}
```

set the z-index for nav positive. make sure that they are in the same div as well, otherwise it won't work